# Making a circle out of rectangles

Tags: java

since I'm not so good in math. I need some help.

I would like to create a circle, but instead of using (x,y, rad), I want to make a circle using rectangles. My canvas WIDTH and HEIGHT are 1200 (pixels).
I want to place my circle the following way : x = WIDTH/3*2, y = HEIGHT/3.
With a radius of 500.

I've started to create a for loop of rectangles, but something goes wrong.
Here's what I did :

```
//not really important, just colors
Color Planet1 = new Color(68,243,252);
Color Planet2 = new Color(179, 225, 249);

int nbDegrade = 100;

// What I wanted to make is 2 for loops, to make 2 half circles.
        for(int i = 1; i < 250; ++i) {
            //this is setting a color with color mixture code
            painter.setColor(mixture(Planet1, Planet2,(double)i/nbDegrade));
            //fillRectangle code (x, y, width, height)
            painter.fillRectangle(WIDTH/3*2 + i,HEIGHT/3 - i,1,i *2);
}
```

I feel like I must use tan function, but have no idea how to do it.

Comment: You could implement the midpoint circle algorithm, I don't know what tan would be for

Comment: You know the radius, so for each width value up to sqrt(0.5)*radius you need the other value using pythagoras. You only need half the values as the other half swaps the width and height.

Comment: Please post [mcve] to show what you did and what is the desired result.

Comment: To expand on what @PeterLawrey was saying, I believe you would get the value for height as `height = 2*sqrt(radius-i*x)`, where x is the radius over the number of segments.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.